# Does Samsung Android phones have issues with application making network requests during Application onCreate?

Tags: android

Our Android app makes a few http request during `Application::onCreate`. Looking in Firebase we see quite a lot of non-fatal exceptions like this:

```
Caused by java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xxx": No address associated with hostname
   at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:156)
   at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
   at okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.java:34)
```

This seems to only affect Samsung devices, but we have been unable to re-produce the problem with any of our Samsung test devices. Is there a rule saying that Android applications should not make requests at this point in the application boot process?

Comment: You cannot make requests in onCreate() or any other function as the actual network call is done in a thread.

Comment: True enough, the actual call is done on a different thread, but it is triggered when the application is in `Application:onCreate`. It is weird that this only seems to be a problem on Samsung devices.

Comment: Is your app started by the user or automatically at boot?